# Make an object rotate from 0 to 360 degrees by using the trigger button on the htc vive controller

Tags: game-mechanics

Hello I would like to be able to make a sphere that is attached to a cube rotate  from 0 to 360 degrees by pressing the trigger on the vive controller. As the sphere rotates I want it to be able to stop at any of the degrees in rotation. For example I press the trigger and the sphere starts rotating but I can stop the rotating at 190 degrees or 10 degrees or 359 degrees etc... I would appreciate any suggestions. 
Best Regards,
Rafman27

Comment: Can you give us some information on where you're starting from? What engine / framework are you using, and what have you gotten working so far? (For instance: have you successfully read data from the controller trigger? Have you created and attached your cube and sphere objects? Have you been able to make the objects rotate? Do you have a partly working version that needs debugging?) These specifics will help us target the answers to the steps you need help with. Please edit your question to ensure it contains all of the relevant information.

Comment: I am using the unity engine. I have my scene set up but I don't have the controller's implemented nor reading date. I essential have a long cube with a small sphere attached at the top and I want to make the sphere to be able to rotate when I press the trigger from 0,1,2,3...359,360 degrees. So when I release trigger it will stop at whatever degree I want it too. Later I want to implement a screen under the sphere that tells you what degree you stopped at. I'm new to developing and using the unity engine but hope I can accomplish this.

Comment: Proceed one step at a time then. Edit the question to "How do I read trigger input from the Vive controller in Unity?" Then, once you have an answer to that, ask a new question, "Here's my code for reading the trigger. How do I rotate my object as long as the trigger is held?" etc. Keeping each question focused will make it easier to get good answers — you don't need to wait for someone who's experienced in all parts of the problem to come along, just someone who knows how to do the step you're asking about. It also makes the question look less like "implement this complete feature for me" ;)